# Rails 4 Include Helper inside Service Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, helper, service-object

I am currently trying to use a Devise helper inside a service object

```
class ServiceObject
    include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
```

But I get

```
undefined method `helper_method' for ServiceObject:Class
```

Any idea how to use such a helper inside the service object?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: create a user inside the service object and in case that fails, call warden.cutsom_failure! which is devise helper method

Comment: ok. but loading an entire module that is supposed to be work in ActionController context into an other class doesnt seem like a good solution to me..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `helper_method` is a method defined by `ActionController::Base`. So including the module only works in subclasses of them.

If the helper is already included in your `ApplicationController` you could simply use `ApplicationController.new.method_to_call`

Answer (score 0):

Try using presentar. Probably you can use decorator gem. So that you can keep your presentation layer seperate and can be easily used any level of framework stack.